# how to find a website vulnerabilities

Tags: xss, security, csrf

Has anyone got the idea how to find a website vulnerabilities issues?
like:

- Log in as the user test Find the admin control page as a non adminuser
- Get the website to print out full debug information for an error
- Using a diﬀerent method from part (1), log in as user1@gmail.com
- Use an XSS attack to open a pop up window displaying a website of your
  choice1
- Describe how a similar XSS attack could be used to log in as
  admin
- Get the store to owe you money Log in as the user admin
- Access the basket of a user, while not logged on as that user
- Describe a    CSRF attack that can be used to change someones password

Many thanks

Comment: I note from your profile that you're currently a student; is this homework? If so, please add the "homework" tag. And also, please ask a more specific question; SO users generally frown upon 'please do my work for me' questions.

Comment: The answers would fill a book.

Comment: No I am not student anymore!! I am working as a network engineer, but trying to read more about security!

Comment: @MagicDaffodil: Ah, then it sounds like you want suggestions of reference material (books, etc.). Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: No I am not looking for a reference as I already got plenty!

Comment: @Magic, where did you come up with that list?

Comment: Whether you realize it or not, you're asking "how do I hack". And despite the stigma that surrounds it, learning how to hack takes years and years of in-depth knowledge about a system. There's no laundry list of steps that will let you in to a system (actually that's not true, those are called script-kiddie tools -- for god's sake don't be a script kiddie). The point being you need to do a lot of learning. Read papers like "smashing the stack for fun and profit".

Comment: If you're not looking material like books (or the OWASP links I posted), then I'm afraid your question is no more answerable that "has anyone got the idea how to program?". Other than the literalist but useless answer 'yes'.

Answer (score 2):

The [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) maintains several guides describing the types of attacks that can be done on web applications. You may want to start with:

- The [Getting Started Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Getting_Started)
- [The Top 10 Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) which documents the most common types of vulnerabilities
- [The Guide Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide) which is attempting to build in-depth documentation of vulnerability classes
- [The Testing Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Testing_Project)

In addition, other vendors have their own lists; for example, [Microsoft has one that is no longer updated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648647.aspx).